Understanding an Activity's active observation lifecycle in Jetpack
From https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata?_gl=1*1cojxn8*_up*MQ..*_ga*MTAzMzM5MjI1NS4xNzEyODM1MDAx*_ga_6HH9YJMN9M*MTcxMjgzNTAwMS4xLjAuMTcxMjgzNTAwMS4wLjAuMA.. an observer is active if its lifecycle is in the STARTED or RESUMED state.
Recently I ran an experiment where I logged observation of livedata for a fragment and an activity.
Activity example
class MovieActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewmodel: MoviesViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewmodel.moviesState.observe(this) {
            Log.i("TRACE", "observed $it")
        }
    }

Fragment example
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
    viewmodel.moviesState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            Log.i("TRACE", "observed $it") }

MoviesViewModel.kt
class MoviesViewModel(private val moviesRepository: MoviesRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _moviesState = MutableLiveData<List<Movie>>()
    val moviesState: LiveData<List<Movie>> = _moviesState
    
    init {
        _moviesState.value = moviesRepository.getTopRatedMovies()
    }

If I'm in a fragment and navigate to a second fragment, then press back to return it triggered an observation.  Makes sense because the fragment onStart() is called again when you return.
But if I'm in an activity and navigate to a second Activity, then press back to return it does not trigger an observation.  Why not if Activity onStart() is called again when you return?
I then tried it on a Fragment that launches a DialogFragment.
class FirstFragment: Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: FirstViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
        viewModel.dialogText.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { enteredStr ->
            Log.d("TRACE", "observe $it")
            editText.setText(enteredStr)
        }

        val launchBtn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.launch)
        launchBtn.setOnClickListener {
            SelectDialogFragment().show(
                childFragmentManager,
                "DIALOG"
            )
        }
        return view

package com.example.communication

import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels

class SelectDialogFragment: DialogFragment() {

    private val viewModel: FirstViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val view = requireActivity().layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.dialog_layout, null
        )
        val et = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.text_dialog)

        return AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("Set Text") { dialog, _ ->
                viewModel.setDialogText(et.text.toString())
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.cancel()
            }
            .create()
    }
}

If I close the dialog to return to FirstFragment an observation occurs, but onStart() was not called.  So this begs the question of what a STARTED or RESUMED state means since it is independent of onStart() or onResume() being called, and does not mean resume in the colloquial sense, otherwise the activity would see another observation.
